# Why query won't save in csv file while it's seems normal in postgresql console

Tags: html, postgresql, csv

I have this query which i want to save in csv file or html

```
select phone_number, count(driver_callsign), driver_callsign from archived_order where data like '%"ptt":3%' and completed is true and ds_id = 16 and created > (select current_date - interval '7 days') group by archived_order.phone_number, archived_order.driver_callsign HAVING COUNT(driver_callsign) > 1;
```

When i using it in psql console - it seems normal. There is output:

```
 phone_number  | count | driver_callsign
---------------+-------+-----------------
 +380502270347 |     2 | 6686
 +380502336770 |     2 | 4996
```

When i'm using this command:

```
psql -t -A -F ';' -h localhost -U username -c "select phone_number, count(driver_callsign), driver_callsign from archived_order where data like '%"ptt":3%' and completed is true and ds_id = 16 and created > (select current_date - interval '1 days') group by archived_order.phone_number, archived_order.driver_callsign HAVING COUNT(driver_callsign) > 1;" > SomeName.csv
```

It doesn't writing anything there.

If someone can help to fix it, i will appreciate it.

Comment: The command to export data is `COPY (SELECT ... FROM ...) TO 'your_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER`. The rest of the options are shown here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: Look comment in answer below please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.

Try using `stdout` to direct the output of your query to a file using `psql` from your console. The following example creates a file in the client machine:

```
$ psql -c "COPY (your query here!) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ';'" > file.csv
```

If you wish to have this output file in the **server** you might wanna try this:

```
$ psql -c "COPY (your query here!) TO '/path/to/file.csv'"
```

Comment: i'm going to use this query in cron, and there's input like `usr/bin/psql -h localhost -U etaxi_prod_due etaxi_prod_due --html -c "<query>">>/home/www/etaxi-prod-due/tmp/shara.html`

Comment: @Lotarc doesn't the first option of my answer work? Just place the command in your cron job: `$ sr/bin/psql -h localhost -U etaxi_prod_due etaxi_prod_due --html  -c "COPY (<query>) TO STDOUT" > /home/www/etaxi-prod-due/tmp/shara.html`

Comment: oh i see i'll try

Comment: Alright, i tried it with different combination. It's not working for me)
I guess it's all because of count's and having count. But i don't know how to optimize to do this kind of stuff without it

Comment: which error message are you getting? @Lotarc 
It might be the `"` you have in your strings. Have you tried escaping them?

Comment: i'm getting no erros, just an empty file

Comment: @Lotarc quite strange. Does the query work at all? If you use `... -c "COPY (<query>) TO STDOUT"` and the file is still empty it might be that your query isn't returning anything and the problem isn't `copy` but the query itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204048/discussion-between-lotarc-and-jim-jones).

Comment: I found a solution. It was a json data which was getting wrong value, but before it's worked correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lotarc Great to know it worked after all :) Cheers!