# Copy output of WITH subquery to CSV in postgres

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-copy

I am trying to save the output of below 'WITH' sub-query to a csv file.

```
 WITH mer9 AS (
                SELECT *, 
                        substring(seq_window_mut_9mers, split9.start, 9)
                FROM split9
        ),

    mer23 AS (
                  SELECT *, 
                        substring(seq_window_mut_23mers, split23.start, 23)
                   FROM split23
        ),

    dataset AS (
                SELECT *
                    FROM table 
                    INNER JOIN mer9 ON mer9.seq_window_mut_9mers = table.seq_window_mut_9mers
                    INNER JOIN mer23 ON mer23.seq_window_mut_23mers = table.seq_window_mut_23mers

        )

COPY (SELECT * FROM dataset) TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (format CSV);
```

After running the query, I am getting an error:

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "COPY"
  Position: 3566  [Script position: 3566 - 3570]
```

Comment: `copy (with ( ..) select ...) to `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result sets generated from a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) cannot be accessed in a different query. A CTE creates a sort of "temporary table" that only exists in the current query. That being said, put your CTE inside of the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html) statement and it should work, e.g.

```
COPY (
 WITH mer9 AS (
  SELECT *, substring(seq_window_mut_9mers, split9.start, 9)
  FROM split9),
 mer23 AS (
  SELECT *, substring(seq_window_mut_23mers, split23.start, 23)
  FROM split23),
 dataset AS (
  SELECT * FROM table 
  INNER JOIN mer9 ON mer9.seq_window_mut_9mers = table.seq_window_mut_9mers
  INNER JOIN mer23 ON mer23.seq_window_mut_23mers = table.seq_window_mut_23mers
 )
) TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (format CSV);
```

**Edit**. As pointed out by *@a_horse_with_no_name*:

Keep in mind that this command will create a file in the server. If you wish to create a file with the output in the client, consider using `STDOUT` in your `COPY` command, e.g. using [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html):

```
$ psql -d yourdb -h yourdbhost -U your_user -c "COPY (WITH..) TO STDOUT" > file.csv
```

See also this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283138/why-query-wont-save-in-csv-file-while-its-seems-normal-in-postgresql-console/59283600#59283600).

Comment: Is it possible to save the output in current directory, instead of tmp?

Comment: @rshar: `copy` creates the file **on the server** - and the Postgres service process does not really have a "current directory". And if it does, it will most probably not be what you think it is.

Comment: @rshar if you wish to have the output file in the client,  consider using `STDOUT`. I just added this option in my asnwer

Comment: @JimJones: or use `\copy` in `psql`

Comment: I am wriiting the output to /tmp folder however I am unable to see the csv. Query is not giving me any error. In principle, I should be able to see the csv file

Comment: @rshar what happens if you use `stdout` instead?

Comment: Im getting a syntax error putting the CTE inside the COPY parenthesis

"ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"