# Run stored function for each row and then export to CSV file

Tags: postgresql

I have a `users` table, and I have a stored function `get_user_points(int user_id): int`.
How can I call this procedure for each row in the user's table, then compare the returned value (amount of points)  if it is bigger than 100 and if true add user_id to export in the `.csv` file (if not bigger than 100 just ignore row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but the following should do what you want:

```
select user_id
from users 
where get_user_points(user_id) > 100
```

The process to export that to a .csv file depends on the SQL client you are using. In `psql` you could e.g. use `\copy`

Answer (score 1):

Use your function in the WHERE clause and put your query inside COPY

```
COPY (
  SELECT * 
  FROM user_table WHERE get_user_points(int user_id) > 100
) TO '/path/to/file.csv'
```

- Keep in mind that the file will be created in the database server. If client and server are in different machines you have to stick to [`TO STDOUT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59283600/2275388) or to the option provided by @a_horse_with_no_name